# Emergency treatment for puppy with a punctured lung

Tags: dogs, medicines

If a puppy has a punctured lung, is there anything I can do to keep it alive until we reach the vet?

Because external injuries can be treated by taking the puppy to doctor, but when adult dogs make a hole with teeth into puppy' lung, I have found that they just die in short time (5-50 seconds) and I do not have even time to take it to the hospital, So in such serious cases how can I save them? :(

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You in advance.

**Edit:**

GOD just saved one more street dog today by me by pumping it, fortunately it's lung was not holed, but it was forced from height and force towards one marble stone. It tried to get up but could not, it left control of body.

It started dying and its tongue came out of its mouth, I had seen people forcing chest of humans. So I did the same with the dog with chanting of holy name of GOD. The dog vomited and came back to life. It was so happy moment for me. I fed it little water, it is alive. Yes it is scared and was lucky that its case was different from lung hole. But immediate treatment of chest pushing helped me this time. I thank GOD especially for his compassion. **I took it to hospital even after 15 minutes...** But yes he is alive today. :)

I am wondering if I would have done the same with my puppy, it would be alive. :(

f we put our fingers on lung hole will it work? Does pumping work in punctured lung case? What emergency treatment should I do?

But I shared this one because this treatment worked for me today.

Comment: I think if a dog dies from a traumatic injury in less than a minute, that even if it were at the vet at that very moment, it's extremely likely they still would be able to save it. It isn't really a matter of knowing an emergency medical technique, because anything that might have been done for animals with that severe an injury would certainly be beyond anyone who doesn't have formal training.

Answer (score 6):

Some injuries are just too much for a puppy to survive.  A punctured lung is going to be one of those.  Even if the vet was immediately available and ready to perform what ever procedures are required when it happens, there is good chance you are still going to lose the puppy.

Your situation is tragic and very sad, unfortunately there is not always a happy ending even when we do everything right.  For this reason it is recommended any time you are outside of your home environment, that you keep your dog on a leash so that you can prevent the animal from charging recklessly toward unfamiliar dogs, out in front of traffic, or even other people.

I am so sorry you had to endure this.